# subtracting column from unmatched dataFrame by mapping it to matching column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two DataFrame as listed below

```py
plusMinusOne = pd.DataFrame({0: [2459650, 2459650,2459650,2459654,2459654,2459654,2459660], 1: [100, 90,80,14,15,16,2]},index=[3,4,5,12,13,14,27])


bias = pd.DataFrame({0: [2459651, 2459652,2459653,2459655,2459656,2459658,2459659], 1: [10, 20,30,40,50,60,70]})
```

I have to subtract plusMinusOne's 1st column with bias 1th column by matching the bias 0th column with plusMinusOne's 0th column.

As `2459650` is not present in bias dataFrame i have to check for `2459651/2459649` from bias and subtract any one's value from that. I have to look for 1 above or 1 below from bias and then subtract the value for every row

I was trying like this.

```py
for i in plusMinusOne[0]:
   if i+1 in bias[0].values:
       plusMinusOne[1] = plusMinusOne[1].sub(plusMinusOne[0].map(
            bias.assign(key=bias[0]-1).set_index('key')[1]), fill_value=0)
       break
   elif i-1 in bias[0].values:
       plusMinusOne[1] = plusMinusOne[1].sub(plusMinusOne[0].map(
            bias.assign(key=bias[0]+1).set_index('key')[1]), fill_value=0)
       break
```

My expected output is :

```
plusMinusOne 

2459650   90
2459650   80
2459650   70
2459654  -26
2459654  -25
2459654  -24
2459660  -68
```

Comment: sir what if i have to do it like if +-3 or greater than that is missing than i have to subtract from +-3 only

Comment: like sir i have 2459647 and 2459648 in df1 i have to subtract from 2459651 in df2 only . Anything lesser than 2459648 will be subtracted from 2459651 and anything greater than 2459662 will be subtracted from 2459659 in df2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vectorized solution,

```
def bias_diff(row):
    value = 0
    if (row[0] == bias[0]).any():
        value = row[1] - bias[(row[0]) == bias[0]].iloc[0,1]
    elif ((row[0]+1) == bias[0]).any():
        value = row[1] - bias[(row[0]+1) == bias[0]].iloc[0,1]
    else:
        value = row[1] - bias[(row[0]-1) == bias[0]].iloc[0,1]
    return value


plusMinusOne[1] = plusMinusOne.apply(bias_diff, axis=1)
print(plusMinusOne)
```

Output

```
          0   1
3   2459650  90
4   2459650  80
5   2459650  70
12  2459654 -26
13  2459654 -25
14  2459654 -24
27  2459660 -68
```

Comment: sir as it is working for +1 and -1, I have to check for +3 and -3 and any file greater than +3 and -3 will map to 3 only. will it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an efficient code, but this work for your case.This will work for which difference you want by changing the diff variable value

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({0: [2459650, 2459650,2459650,2459654,2459654,2459654,2459660], 1: [100, 90,80,14,15,16,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0: [2459651, 2459652,2459653,2459655,2459656,2459658,2459659], 1: [10, 20,30,40,50,60,70]})

diff = 3
def data_process(df1,df2,i,diff):
    data = None
    for j in range(len(df2)):
        if df1[0][i] == df2[0][j]:
            data = df1[1][i]-df2[1][j]
        else:
            try:
                if (df1[0][i])+diff == df2[0][j]:
                    data =  df1[1][i]-df2[1][j]
                elif (df1[0][i])-diff == df2[0][j]:
                    data =  df1[1][i] - df2[1][j]
            except:
                pass
    return data

processed_data = []
for i in range(len(df1)):
    if data_process(df1,df2,i,diff) is None:
        processed_data.append(df1[1][i])
    else:
        processed_data.append(data_process(df1,df2,i,diff))
df1[2] = processed_data

print(df1[[0,2]])
```

The output dataframe for diff 1 is

```
         0   2
0  2459650  90
1  2459650  80
2  2459650  70
3  2459654 -26
4  2459654 -25
5  2459654 -24
6  2459660 -68
```

the output dataframe for diff 3 is

```
         0     2
0  2459650  70.0
1  2459650  60.0
2  2459650  50.0
3  2459654   4.0
4  2459654   5.0
5  2459654   6.0
6  2459660   2
```

The **2459660** does not contain +3 or -3 combinational value (i.e) **2459657** or **2459663** in second dataframe. so i return the value as it is. Else it will return Nan value instead of 2.

Comment: sir as it is working for +1 and -1, I have to check for +3 and -3 and any file greater than +3 and -3 will map to 3 only. will it be possible?

Comment: It would work but the code is not in efficient way. May the time consumption for loop will be longer.

Comment: can you add the expected output?

Comment: how can i  acheive for >=3 and <=3? efficiency is not the problem sir

Comment: like sir i have `2459647` and `2459648` in df1 i have to subtract from `2459651` in df2 only . Anything lesser than `2459648` will be subtracted from `2459651` and anything greater than `2459662` will be subtracted from `2459659` in df2

Comment: I had editted the code. you change the diff variable value and play around it